# Using re2c with ISO-8859-x

Tags: regex, tokenize, iso-8859-15, re2c

We have some text in ISO-8859-15 for which we want to tokenize. (ISO-8859-15 is ISO-8859-1 with the Euro sign and other common accented characters, for more details see [ISO-8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15#Changes_from_ISO-8859-1)).

I am trying to get the parser to recognize all the characters. The native character representation of the text editors I'm using is UTF-8, so to avoid hidden conversion problems, I'm restricting all `re2c` code to ASCII *e.g.*

```
LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A_WITH_GRAVE      = "\xc0" ;
LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A_WITH_ACUTE      = "\xc1" ;
LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A_WITH_CIRCUMFLEX = "\xc2" ;
LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A_WITH_TILDE      = "\xc3" ;
...
```

Then:

```
UPPER    = [A-Z] | LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A_WITH_GRAVE
                 | LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A_WITH_CIRCUMFLEX
                 | LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_AE
                 | LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_C_WITH_CEDILLA
                 | ...

WORD     = UPPER LOWER* | LOWER+ ;
```

It compiles no problem and runs great on ASCII, but stalls whenever it hits these extended characters.

Has anyone seen this, and is there a way to fix it?

Thank you,

Yimin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I've seen it. Has to do with comparison of signed vs unsigned types for bytes ≥ 128.

Two ways to fix: use `unsigned char` as your default type, *e.g.* `re2c:define:YYCTYPE = "unsigned char";`, or `-funsigned-char` (if using `gcc`, other compilers have equivalent) as a compile flag. You can use the one that interferes with your existing code the least.